# Is JAVA DB compliant with Oracle 11 G?

Tags: java, oracle11g, java-7, derby, java-6

I am using JAVA DB (Part of JDK1.7) for my development environment. We have Oracle 11g on our SIT environment. I was researching whether JAVA DB (Which is based upon Apache Derby) is compliant with Oracle 11g i.e. Will I need some changes in my query structure or code if I try to migrate my code from JAVA DB to Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1):

Java DB and Oracle 11g are not entirely compatible with each other.  Depending on your query's complexity, you may or may not need to port your code.

Comment: In what ways they are incompatible with other, can you please provide link to some reference material where I can research this?

Comment: I don't have any off the top of my head - I might be able to pull some later, but the first difference that comes to my mind is that Derby does not support stored procedures written in Java, while Oracle 11g does.  You may actually be better off asking if a particular feature you're concerned about will run on both Oracle 11g and Derby.

Answer (score 0):

it just require the connection to particular db which are using do need any extra code for db it is same for any database

Answer (score 0):

SQL Compatibility is a big topic. You might want to start here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/SQLvsDerbyFeatures